# Does drawing a card still end your movement after the haunt has begun?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

After the haunt does your turn still end in a newly discovered room that has an event or omen? If so this seems to make it very difficult to get away from monsters.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, your movement will always end after you enter a newly discovered room with a symbol in it. This does mean you can have some claustrophobic haunts, but it is the way the game is played.

Comment: It is more accurate to say that your movement will end. You can still take actions in the newly discovered room.

Comment: Yup, you're right. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your movement will end if you draw a card for **any** reason, whether it was for revealing a new icon-bedecked room or for some other reason (such as opening the Puzzlebox).

From the rulebook (italics mine):

> **Move**
>
> On your turn, you can move up to a number of spaces equal to your character's current **Speed**.  You can perform actions (such as
> using an item or attacking) in the middle of your movement.  However,
> whenever a game effect makes you draw a card *for any reason*, you
> must stop moving for the rest of the turn.

This rule does not change once the haunt has been revealed.